# The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application when delete an email

Tags: outlook, office-js, exchangewebservices

I got an error when try to delete the email address ews ? is there an API that can delete the email with javascript plugin ?

```
     xml  =
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
        +'<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'
        +' xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"'
        +' xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"'
        +' xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
        +'<soap:Header>'
        +'<t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1" />'
        +'</soap:Header>'
        +'<soap:Body>'
        +'    <m:DeleteFolder DeleteType="HardDelete">'
        +'        <m:FolderIds>'
        +'            <t:FolderId Id="'+id+'" />'
        +'        </m:FolderIds>'
        +'    </m:DeleteFolder>'
        +'</soap:Body>'
        +'</soap:Envelope>';

  Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(xml, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

i got an error :

```
code: 9020
message: "The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application."
name: "GenericResponseError"
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync`, we only support a small subset of EWS operations, all documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services). `DeleteFolder` is unsupported, hence the error message. One alternative here is to use [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/office-addin).